# Cannot power on Xbox One from Smartglass or W10 app

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-one, xbox-smartglass

I am attempting to power on my Xbox One from both the Smartglass app on my iPhone and the Xbox app on a Windows 10 PC, but it will not power on. If I manually power it on I can connect fine with both apps. My console is set to instant-on in the settings. The Xbox One is connected via wireless to my home network.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a wired connection---so I don't think that's the issue. Since a lot of people have been reporting issues with this, I assumed it was busted for everyone. Now I'm wondering if there's something in my network setup that is causing issues. I use a Linux (Ubuntu) box as my home gateway---but as far as I know the firewall (UFW) is opened up for my local subnet.

Comment: Try static Ip, and most importantly autosign in on the Xbox.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that finally made this work for me is to login to my router and enable WOL(Wake On Lan). I was also able to verify that this works both wired and wireless.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could do, basically buy a free app:

https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/41nowk/a_little_trick_for_people_unable_tu_turn_on_their/

I've tried the following: https://github.com/Schamper/xbox-remote-power/blob/master/xbox-remote-power.py

That doesn't seem to work.

There's an app on the windows store called "xoon" that doesn't seem to work, either.

If you read the following, ttp://forums.xbox.com/xbox_support/xbox_on_windows_support/f/5411/t/2087453.aspx?pi7406=3#5552260 , 
you'll see at least you're not alone.   Also, it says something about MS looking into it.  I'm hoping they fix it on the next update.

What I find strange is that downloading an app does work.  So it's not like the xbox has gone completely asleep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the "[XOON](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/xoon/9nblggh5fmd1)" app and I had the same issue when I developed the app. I have observed that this problem (cannot turn on the console while in Instant-on mode) exists only for the **wireless** connection.

It works well if you connect your console via the LAN interface (cable connection) to your home network. I have specified this point in the "help" section of the App.

Comment: The "turn on" packet uses UDP 5050 port. Make sure to open it in you firwall, and add a port forwarding rule for it to the internal IP of your console.

Comment: I added the rule but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You don't need any port-forwarding, if you're in your local network. Actually doing that might be a security issue, since others could be able to turn on your Xbox and/or access it from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XBoot One to turn on your Xbox remotely on both Windows and android

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mehradsoft.XBootOne

It will be in Microsoft Store soon too.